# "Error: Cannot find module 'botbuilder'" when trying to use BotFramework

Tags: botframework

I have used npm to download package.json and npm install to install botbuilder and api-ai-recognizer, but it tells me that it cannot find botbuilder. Can someone help me?

I have done the following in my Azure Cloud Shell:

```
mkdir weather-bot
cd weather-bot
npm init
npm install --save botbuilder api-ai-recognizer
cd ~
touch index.js
vi index.js

var builder = require('botbuilder'); 
var connector = new builder.ConsoleConnector().listen(); 
var bot = new builder.UniversalBot(connector); 
bot.dialog('/',function(session){ session.send("You said %s", session.message.text); });
```

After I start the node server

```
node index.js hi You said hi hello You said hello
```

I get the error "Error: Cannot find module 'botbuilder'" .

Comment: You need to provide the relevant code from your bot and the specific error message. It sounds like the package you need didn't actually get installed.

Comment: Okay. I added that in an edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you installed your npm modules in weather-bot (i.e. ~/weather-bot/node_modules), but you have put your index.js file at the root (i.e. ~/index.js). So when you are trying to run your bot, it is looking in ~/node_modules for the `botbuilder` module, but it's not installed there. Try moving your index.js file to your weather-bot directory and see if it works.

Comment: I have tried this and it still gives the same error.

Comment: Can you check the node_modules folder and ensure there is a botbuilder folder within? I can't imagine what the issue would be other than a missing module.

Comment: there is a botbuilder folder in the node_modules folder

Comment: Also, to be clear, I have tried adding the index.js file to both the weather-bot and node_modules folders and neither worked.

Comment: I seem to have no problem locating botbuilder module, but was getting a separate `builder.ConsoleConnector is not a constructor` error. That method appears to be related to V3 bot and older version of botbuilder package (e.g. 3.13.1). Once I installed that version it worked for me, I can't replicate your issue. If the module is there, perhaps for some reason your version of node is looking a different place for it?

Comment: Also, I don't understand your command `node index.js hi You said hi hello You said hello`. I think you should just be running `node undex.js`, then you input "hi" and receive "You said hi" as the response, etc. I entered the command as you had it and all it did was run index.js anyway.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212277/discussion-between-swygerts-and-billoverton).